# Simple encryption algorithm in JAVA with a Key for SDKminVersion 21

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I used AES encryption algorithm, in my app development project, seems that few functions mentioned are supported by minSDK version of 26 and above,

So what other algorithms can I use for encryption and decryption for devices whose SDK version is less than 26.

Provided the encryption should be symmetric and key-based.

And the Algorithm mustn't take more time in encryption as it might increase the run time.

Comment: Can you specify which functionality requires a minimum API of 26?

Comment: getEncoder()
encodeToString()
getDecoder()
decode()

Comment: Those functions are part of the new Base64 class and have nothing to do with AES.  Android has supported AES since the very first version I believe.

Comment: @zaph There doesn't appear to be a valid reason to downgrade from AES to xtea imo. At the moment, it appears the only problem the OP is having is of the "too lazy to research" variety.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Point taken, I do not have any real knowledge of Java.